# Select a different grid based on a converter's value for a UWP app

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, converters

In a UWP app, I have a property that returns 3 values. I want to show a different grid based on this value using a converter. What is the best way to a achieve this? The direction I think I am going to head towards is to create 3 different grid templates, and then set the style to one of these 3 templates based on what the converter returns. Does anyone know if this will work? My grid doesn have to be a grid, it can be a contentcontrol or something like that. I basically want to show a different section of UI based on a property

Thanks

Comment: is this a windows universal app?

Comment: Yes sorry, a UWP app

Comment: I think I might just put all 3 grids in and control their visibility with an enum to visibility converter

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [WindowsStateTriggers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsStateTriggers/) NuGet package.

Once installed you can reference at the top of your xaml

```
xmlns:triggers="using:WindowsStateTriggers"
```

and say you had a property in your Backend class called **IsBusy**

```
public bool IsBusy { get; set; } = false;
```

and for example you had 2 simple Grids in your xaml.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="root">
    <Grid x:Name="RedGrid" Background="Red" Width="200" Height="100" />
    <Grid x:Name="GreenGrid" Background="Green" Width="200" Height="100" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You could setup a Visual State Group to show the Grids based on the IsBusy property. We want the Green Grid to be visible and the Red Grid to be collapsed when IsBusy = true

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="root">
     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
         <VisualStateGroup>
             <VisualState x:Name="IsBusy">
                 <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                     <triggers:EqualsStateTrigger EqualTo="True" Value="{Binding IsBusy, ElementName=root}" />
                 </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                 <VisualState.Setters>
                     <Setter Target="RedGrid.Visibilty" Value="Collapsed"/>
                     <Setter Target="GreenGrid.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                 </VisualState.Setters>
             </VisualState>
         </VisualStateGroup>
     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
     <Grid x:Name="RedGrid" Background="Red" Width="200" Height="100" />
     <Grid x:Name="GreenGrid" Background="Green" Width="200" Height="100" />
 </StackPanel>
```

NB The `{Binding IsBusy, ElementName=root}` depends on your `DataContext` and location of `IsBusy` property. Here its just in the code behind for the page.
Hope that gives you an idea.